# Language Agnostic - Allowable types in function and constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, kotlin, language-agnostic

Most, if not all statically typed languages allow you to specify a single type for a function or constructor parameter; for example

```
function foo(x: string) { ... }

foo("hello")  // works
foo(123)      // error
```

TypeScript is a statically typed super-set of JavaScript, but since JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, TypeScript allows you to be a little more flexible; for example, you can specify more than one *allowable* type.

```
function foo(x: string | number) { ... }

foo("hello")  // works
foo(123)      // works
foo(true)     // error
```

Additionally, in TypeScript this allows you to constrain generic type parameters to specific types only; for example:

```
class Foo<T extends number | string> {
    constructor(x: T) { ... }
}

new Foo("hello")  // works
new Foo(123)      // works
new Foo(true)     // fails
```

**Problem**

I like TypeScript's ability to constrain generic type parameters to specific types only, but I would also like to be able to do this in other languages, namely C# and Kotlin, but as far as I am aware, there is no equivalent construct in these languages to support such a constraint. How would one achieve this in other languages?

**Note:** I'm happy to accept answers in *any* language, not just the ones listed. This is more about higher level thinking and exploring other avenues which could apply across languages.

Comment: For C#, you can use method overloading for the first case

Answer (score 1):

C++20 has a notion of [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) which is able to constraint template parameters in the way you want, and more.  This introduces in the language something which was approximable using a variety of techniques, describing them here seems out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeScript allows you to be a little more flexible; for example, you can specify more than one allowable type.

No, you can't; `number | string` is a single type, called a union type. You can pass a `number` or a `string` because they are both subtypes of `number | string`. But you could also pass any `number | string`.

Similarly, in the second example `T` is not constrained to be either `number` or `string`; it can be `number | string` or any subtype of `number` or `string`. Or even

```
var x = new Foo<123 | "">(123)
```

where again `123 | ""` is a perfectly ordinary TypeScript type.

Scala 3 will have union types; there was [a discussion of union types for Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108), but you can see the team is not interested. For C#, [similarly](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/399).

Answer (score 0):

In **F#** there are the [Sum / Union](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/) types. Looks a lot like what you have in **TypeScript**, but in **F#** they are defined with labels which are used to match against.
Which allow you to have sum type with several cases of the same type. For example:

```
type ShoeSize = 
    | EU of double
    | UK of double
    | US of double
```